# Procedure for building and importing a Boost.python module using GCC?

Tags: c++, python, gcc, boost, boost-python

I've managed to compile a Boost.Python 'first try' but am unsure how to import it into python and call the methods it contains. My source file is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int test(int i)
{
       fprintf(stderr, "%s:\n", __FUNCTION__);
       return i * 5;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ipg)
{
       using namespace boost::python;
       def("test", test);
}
```

My makefile contains:

```
# Which compiler?
CC=c++

# Which flags for object files?
OFLAGS=-c -Wall -fPIC

# Which flags for the output binary?
BFLAGS=-Wall -shared -o ipg

# Which flags for boost python?
BPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/python2.7
BLIBS=-lpython2.7 -lboost_python -lboost_system

# Make.
all: source/python.cpp
    $(CC) $(BOUT) $(BFLAGS) $(BPFLAGS) $? $(BLIBS)
```

and my test script:

```
import sys

# My modules.
import ipg

ipg.test()
```

The output binary is placed alongside the test script, and the test script is run. This results in the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 4, in
>   
>       import ipg ImportError: No module named ipg

What flags should I be using to compile my output binary, and how should I go about importing it into python? I've used boost.Python on Windows before, but that was quite a while ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, if your module is called `ipg`, then you need to be creating a file called `ipg.so`.  Here's a simple makefile;

```
ipg.o:
    g++ -o ipg.o -c ipg.cc -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7
ipg.so: ipg.o
    g++ -shared -o ipg.so ipg.o -lpython2.7 -lboost_python -lboost_system
```

Comment: Wow, that was pretty simple, thanks. Could you explain to me why I need the .so on the end? Does Python perform some sort of behind-the-scenes magic beforehand, requiring the extension as a filtering mechanism?

Comment: It's just simply part of the lookup mechanism.  Depending on the architecture, the importer will look for foo.py (source), foo.pyc (bytecode compiled), foo.pyo (bytecode optimized), foo.pyd (windows extension), foo.so (unix extension), foo.dylib (mac extension).  I'm not certain on the ordering.